# Hierarchical List of Work Items from TFS_Warehouse database

Tags: sql, t-sql, tfs

I am trying to retrieve a hierarchical list of all 'Product Backlog' work items from TFS_Warehouse. Today is my first day working on TFS so I am not really aware of the schema/ or what table to look for.

I found two tables DimWorkItem and FactWorkItemLinkHistory. I tried extracting some information from these but no luck.

What I am trying to do is generate a Release Details list, which will show work items with state like New, Approved... I need to write a TSQL Statement to get this data.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Vishal

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you have already figured this out, but in case anyone else passes by you can use the `GetWorkItemsTree` UDF with a `CROSS APPLY` operator, passing it the root node `System_Id` and the relationship type to be used to traverse the tree, such as:

```
SELECT 
   ...
FROM
    DimWorkItem wi
CROSS APPLY
    GetWorkItemsTree(@TeamProjectCollectionGuid, wi.System_Id, N'Child', DEFAULT) wit
WHERE
    wi.System_Id = @RootId
    AND wi.System_RevisedDate = CONVERT(datetime, '9999', 126) -- latest revision
```

However, this UDF will only traverse a single relationship type and I recall there being a limitation to the traversal depth. If you need something more flexible you'll probably have to write it yourself; I did so using a UDF containing a recursive CTE on the `[FactWorkItemLinkHistory]` table which also provided for traversal of multiple relationship types.

Comment: Thanks for reply. However I did it using WorkItemsAre and LinksAre tables from OLTP database.